# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Modelo could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm starting with Symfony 3 and EasyAdminBundle. My problem is when I tried to edit or create a entity with a foreign key I get an Exception:

> "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Modelo could not be converted to
>   string 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException" in
>   vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\DoctrineType.php
>   at line 59

```
public static function createChoiceLabel($choice)
{
    return (string) $choice;
}
```

VehiculoType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class VehiculoType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('patente')->add('modelo', 'entity');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Vehiculo'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'appbundle_vehiculo';
}
public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->getVehiculo();
}

}
```

And my entity 
    Vehiculo.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
/*** Vehiculo*/
class Vehiculo{
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $patente;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set patente
 *
 * @param string $patente
 *
 * @return Vehiculo
 */
public function setPatente($patente)
{
    $this->patente = $patente;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get patente
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPatente()
{
    return $this->patente;
}
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $oneToOne;


/**
 * Set oneToOne
 *
 * @param string $oneToOne
 *
 * @return Vehiculo
 */
public function setOneToOne($oneToOne)
{
    $this->oneToOne = $oneToOne;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get oneToOne
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getOneToOne()
{
    return $this->oneToOne;
}
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Modelo
 */
private $modelo;


/**
 * Set modelo
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Modelo $modelo
 *
 * @return Vehiculo
 */
public function setModelo(\AppBundle\Entity\Modelo $modelo = null)
{
    $this->modelo = $modelo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get modelo
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Modelo
 */
public function getModelo()
{
    return $this->modelo;
}
}
```

Comment: implements the __toString() method in the Modelo class and let return a string representation of the object (something like the name)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the __toString() method in your entity.

The easyAdmin bundle is trying to show you the entity that is mapped in the New and Edit view.
But it doesn't know how to show it.

Simply adding the following to your entity should resolve it (you can replace patente if another string makes more sense):

```
    public function __toString()
{
    return $this->patente;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `modelo` field should define the [choice_label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage) option in order to display correctly something that allows to identify the entity:

```
$builder->add('patente')->add('modelo', 'entity', [
    'choice_label' => 'name'
]);
```

Replace `name` with a property implemented by the `Modelo` entity.